# Learning To Write Macros

Tags: excel

I'm working on creating a simple budget in Excel. I want to add Macros for the sake of learning, so some of the things I am going to ask to do are easily just added.

I have each month for the year split into several categories, as expenses (or income) come in I would like to be able to choose a category from a drop-down list - which would then prompt an input box to enter the value of the expense/income. Once Okay is selected, I would like the value to be added to the current value in the cell. Here is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
ComboBox1.Clear
ComboBox1.Value = ""
With Sheet3.ComboBox1
    .AddItem "Income"
    .AddItem "Asha"
    .AddItem "Grocery"
    .AddItem "Misc."
    .AddItem "Food/Cafe"
    .AddItem "To Sarah"
    .AddItem "Student Loan"
    .AddItem "Ally Savings"
    .AddItem "Insurance"
    End With
End Sub

Sub GetValue()
    Dim PopUp As Variant
    PopUp = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter Amount", Default:="Only Numbers", Type:=1)

End Sub
```

[image]

I'm sure I can simply do this with a pivot table but that is going to teach me any think about writing Macros. Any tips would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your question is. Is there a specific point that you are stuck on? If so, what? Otherwise, the question is too unfocused and reads like a request for a custom tutorial which steps you through the creation of a whole program.

Comment: One thing you will need to do is identify what cell you want the value chosen from the ComboBox  to go into, so you can reference it with the `Sub GetValue()`.  Something like `Range("[Enter Cell Here]") = ComboBox.Value`.  You will then need to tell the `GetValue()` sub where to place the Dollar amount based on the cell that references the ComboBox value.

Comment: Thank you Zack, I will give this a try and see what I can come up with.